# Does countably infinite number of zeros add to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if you add zero infinite number of times then answer is not zero and standard example of $1-1+1-1+1\ldots$ is given, but it is uncountable set and I want to ask whether countably infinite number of zeros add up to zero?

Comment: You need a rigorous definition of uncountable addition before this can be answered.

Comment: I'm not sure why the $1 - 1 + 1 - \ldots$ would be considered uncountable. I also think it's arguable whether you should even call it a sum of $0$s, as I don't even see a single $0$ term.

Comment: You can view it as (1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+....  Although that is not my major concern. I am a beginner and doing my first course in real analysis and I dont really know whether I am correct or not.     All I want to know wether zero added countably infinite times leads zero or not.

Comment: @Paul, does this not just seem like a crude version of integrating over the null function? ah nevermind, rieman integrals actually use "normal" series...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean this
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n, \ a_n=0, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
the answer is yes. Actually, determine the sequence $\{S_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of partial sums $S_n:= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n$ and notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

In algebra, $\sum_{i\in I}a_i$ is *defined* only if there is a finite subset $J\subseteq I$ such that $a_i=0$ for all $i\in I\setminus J$, i.e., if almost all summands are zero, and in this case $\sum_{i\in I}a_i:=\sum_{i\in J}a_i$. In particular,  we get $$\sum_{i\in I}0=0$$ no matter what $I$ is (it might even be much larger than $\Bbb N$, in particular uncountable and not endowed with a natural order).

In analysis, the symbol $\sum$ is not only used for sums, but also for series, which are considered as a limit of finite sums. But as a finite sum of zeroes is zero, we obtain $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty 0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n 0=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.$$